# Sqlplus login without password

Tags: oracle, passwords, sqlplus

I installed Oracle 11gR2 on my linux server. When I want to login via sys user on my db, I enter "sys as sysdba" and when system give password , I push enter and I can login on my db with sqlplus.

But, when I try to connect on Windows with PL-SQL tool, system wants to password. If I didn't write password (I defined password, password is "sys"), I cannot login on my db.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install oracle, it creates OSDBA and OSOPER groups. Any members of this groups will have OS authentication and can logon without a password.

When you connect from another machine, it's a remote connection and you must enter the password.

More info in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/dba.htm#i1006534).

Answer (score 3):

When you connect on the same server you're being [authenticated by the operating system](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/authentication.htm#autoId25); you can give any password you like, or it's more common to use `/ as sysdba`.

When you connect from PL/SQL it'a a remote connection; operating system authentication isn't possible, so you're using [password authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/authentication.htm#autoId26).

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem and even with Oracle 12c on my linux server and what i did was that each time I open a new terminal I first type

"*export TWO_TASK=*"

(without the the quotations) followed by pressing

*enter*.

Next I could then go ahead to type *sqlplus "/as sysdba"* (now as it is with the quotations)

to connect and continue.